# Ressources for IntraWeb / VCL for the Web

Tags: delphi, intraweb, intraweb-10

I am aware of the news groups at atozed.intraweb.* as well as the [online manual](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/docs/) and [pdf manual](http://downloads.atozed.com/intraweb/IntrawebManual.pdf), [Bob Swart's IntraWeb book](http://www.bobswart.nl/Weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:2160), and the [spellbook](http://research.pdmagic.com/iw/html/).

Some of these resources are outdated, some are rather minimalistic. Are there other sources available?

This seems to be even more prevailing as the [chat room](http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/Blog/20080903.DE.aspx) is not available any longer due to lack of public chats in the newest Skype version. (I do not know how the quality of help in the chat room was, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also old tools of http://www.arcanatech.com
and elite suite in opensource: http://code.google.com/p/iwelite/

book: http://www.lulu.com/content/paperback-book/delphi-2007-for-win32-vcl-for-the-web-development/2659447

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned, most likely known:
Blog Hadi Hariri: http://hadihariri.com/blogengine
Blog Olaf Monien: http://www.monien.net/blog/
Gran Primo: http://www.multite.es/granprimo/intraweb.htm
Experts-Exchange: http://www.experts-exchange.com

Older components:
Stefan van As: http://svanas.dynip.com/IxIW/

Some articles:
Swiss Delphi center: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showarticle.php?id=6

Currently unavailable, still in Google cache:
Felix Colibri: [Google Cache](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:BWGNawCAWUgJ:www.felix-colibri.com/papers/web/intraweb_architecture/intraweb_architecture.html+intraweb+delphi&cd=30&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl)

Non English (use Google translate):
NLDelphi Forum: http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/search.php?searchid=1293691

And not to be forgotten:
Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Marco Cantu's [Delphi 2007 Handbook](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/handbook_cover.html) can be of some help, as it contains a chapter on Intraweb. It is however somewhat old, maybe his [2009 Handbook](http://www.marcocantu.com/dh2009/) has some newer information.

If you need additional Intraweb controls, you could look at [TMS Intraweb controls](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/products.asp?t=iw) although I myself have never used them.